# Disable browser caching for css and js file during development

Tags: caching, browser-cache

How can we disable browser cache during application development process so that whenever we make any changes to the css or js files in localhost(or any development environment) we don't have to do a hard refresh on the browser to see the changes

Comment: You can append a random string (or the time stamp when the file is updated) as a query string at the end of the resource, e.g. `functions.js?v=1234567`. This will effectively force the browser to retrieve the resource again regardless of its cache.

Comment: You could test and debug your application in Browsers "private mode".

Answer (score 3):

Try this for all css and js. This example you should add time in all css and js

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />

or
<link href="/css/styles.css?ver=<?php echo time();?>" rel="stylesheet">

or
 <script src="/js/site.js?ver=<?php echo time();?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers (Chrome and Firefox are shown in the screenshots below) have an option in the Network tab of the Developer's Tools to disable caching while the Developer Tools are open.

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 1):

caching is good for fast development, but in case of chrome you can right click on the refresh button and find the options:

[image]

Hope this helps?