# Visual Studio 2017 Debugging - Disable Browser Cache

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, disable-caching

I use Visual Studio 2017 for web development pretty heavily, and when you let it open a browser (Chrome is my preference, though this would apply to Edge) it often loads cached versions of scripts and CSS. I know I can go to the `Network` tab and choose `Disable Cache`, but is there a way to get VS to just always load the browser with that option selected?

Comment: **for chrome :**
resolved in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628864/disable-browser-caching-for-css-and-js-file-during-development/52275910#52275910](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628864/disable-browser-caching-for-css-and-js-file-during-development/52275910#52275910)

Comment: I was already using the hard refresh option - this was more of a Visual Studio question, because every time Chrome launches in debug, it starts a new session (which isn't tied to my normal Chrome instance, doesn't have me logged in, etc.) and the cache was always re-enabled. I was hoping there was a way to tell VS to stop doing that :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can point cache dir to null using startup arguments for chrome.
This will disable any caching.

First manage browsers

[image: browser select]

Then add new Chrome browser with attribute: `--disk-cache-dir=null`

[image: add chrome with argument]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: It wasn't working for me at first, but after I close all my visual studio and chrome, it worked! Thanks... :)

Comment: WOW! I wish I could do that, but I am running Visual Studio 2022 and cannot see how to add it - I just select Google Chrome - but can see no way to edit it. The Add button is not in this version. I found out how to add it. I clicked on "Browse With".

Answer (score 0):

•   Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General : CHECK "Enable Just My Code".

•   Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols

•   Click on the "..." button and create/select a new folder somewhere on your local computer to store cached symbols.  Then Click on "Load all symbols" and wait for the symbols to be downloaded from Microsoft's servers, which may take a while. Note that Load all symbols button is only available while debugging.

•   UNCHECK the checkmark next to "Microsoft Symbol Servers" to prevent Visual Studio from remotely querying the Microsoft servers. -> Click "OK".

Comment: I'm not sure this solves my question? It's not a matter of speed - it's telling Chrome/Edge to disable their local JS/CSS caching whenever VS opens the browser instead of me having to remember to do this every time.