# Blazor cannot find or is ignoring scoped CSS

Tags: css, razor, blazor

I have created a Cart.razor.css file that is a child in the directory Cart.razor. As I understand, this is what is known as a scoped CSS file within Razor. I have read the Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and as far as I can see the CSS (Cart.razor.css) file should be automatically included and be usable from within the parent (Cart.razor) file. However in my example it is not.

[Here is an image of the file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZmtb.png)

The Problem here is that no matter what I do. The CSS contained within the scoped CSS file will not be executed.

Here is some of the Cart.razor file that displays the attempt to utilize the custom CSS. Notice `"btn-delete"`.

```
<button class="btn-delete" @onclick="@(() => DeleteItem(item))">
```

Here is the some of the Cart.razor.css file.

```
.btn-delete{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.btn-delete:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[Here is an image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNZqC.png)

As you can see the button is clearly not red or borderless.

My questions are:

- Do I need to somehow include the CSS sheet within the razor file?
- Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm using Rider not
  Visual Studio?

Comment: The Keybind does not work for me, What is it support to trigger within the IDE?

Comment: you said the directory is Car.razor and the css Cart.razor.css. Was it a misunderstanding?

Comment: In the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZmtb.png

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I Created a `WebAssembly project` from scratch; added a `counter.razor.css` file; added your `css` and the `button` element to the `counter.razor` file. It all worked. Can you do the same please? If it still doesn't work, maybe try it on VS just to clear the hypothesis, even though I doubt such a major flaw wouldn't have been solved already (I don't use Rider).

Comment: A few things to check: (1) you are using .NET 5 or 6 ? (2) what is the _rendered_ HTML of your button (on the browser). It should be something like this: `<button class="btn-delete" b-xxghqgvycs="">Delete</button>`. The `b-xxghqgvycs` is the selector tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your index.html (for Webassembly) or _Host.cshtml (for Server) if you have added the stylesheet reference in the **head** section:

```html
<head>
...
    <link href="<applicationName>.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

this file will be *composed* with all yours CSS isolation files.

After that, I've tested your code and the result is:
[image: Test Delete button]

Two other possible issue to check:

1. in case you have upgraded the project, check your **Project.Client.csproj** and remove the line `<RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>` from the `<PropertyGroup>`
2. check if the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` system variable is set to `Development`

Comment: I checked the index.html client side and it already contains that exact line. With the a appropriate application name. There is one peculiarity, it is underlined and within the context actions it asks me if I would like to create the file. Is <applicationName>.Client.styles.css used internally without an actual file existing or is there supposed to be a file at the location <applicationName>.Client.styles.css?

Comment: The _underline_ warning message is not a problem: the file will be created at runtime

Comment: Have you checked is there's any problem in your browser dev tools ?

Comment: Look at my answer, I've added some other checks todo

Comment: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"

Comment: This tip worked for me, but I needed to add the <applicationName> project name without "Client" to the index.html header section for the WebAssembly version.

Answer (score 8):

I found the browser was caching the old css and not noticing the change caused by the new scoped css file. Doing a Ctrl F5 reload in the browser loaded the expected css.

Comment: Thanks for that, probably saved me hours of pain. God I have web development :D

Comment: This was it for me as well. This is a frustrating scenario, but setting VS to not use cache when debugging, might help with alleviating unexpected results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541177/visual-studio-2017-debugging-disable-browser-cache

Answer (score 3):

For .Net7 Blazor, you need to specify the app name explicitly (the wildcards , , etc no longer works, apparently).
In the index.html file you would put something like this in:

```
<link href="MyApplicationName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This coupled with clearing the cache everytime (or setting the browser to always clear the cache) will work 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Nicola's answer,
If you only have a WebAssembly project, you need `<AppName>.styles.css` to be imported in `index.html`.

Comment: This tip worked for me, the project name without the 'Client' in the head section index.html for WebAssembly version.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of my project and forgot to change it in the <link ... /> line. Updating that fixed it in my case.